# Import a cert file as a string using webpack

Tags: import, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader, raw-loader

I was really hoping I'd be able to use webpack to load a certificate file containing text using the `raw-loader`. Unfortunately it fails at the  `-`'s in the first line: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.
 As a test I removed the first `-----`, and then it fails at a " " (space) character.

Seemed like a much simpler solution than using `fs` and a callback.

To clarify, i'd like to be able to do this:

```
import caCert from './cacert';
```

Comment: just-boris' answer should work. Your description sounds like the raw-loader is not executed. You should check your regexes.

Comment: I'll try it out again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to load some file via loader, add loader name as prefix to your import:

```
import caCert from 'raw!./cacert';
```

Also, you can setup your loader in webpack config to match appropriate files by their names

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /cacert$/,
      loaders: [ 'raw-loader' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Now needs to be 'raw-loader'